# Xcode Swift 3.0 macOS (Sierra) app unable to create file, no permission

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, macos-sierra

I'm fairly new to Xcode and Swift. I'm trying to create a file called "file.txt" in my Documents directory and getting the error "You don’t have permission to save the file."

Ultimately, I DO NOT want to use the default Documents directory as I'm using FIFinderSyncController to watch everything ("/").

```
    let targetFile = (FIFinderSyncController.default().targetedURL()?.path)! + "/file.txt"

    NSLog("%@", targetFile as NSString)

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if fileManager.fileExists( atPath: (targetFile) ) == false {

        do {
            let targetString = (FIFinderSyncController.default().targetedURL()?.path)! + "/Untitled.txt"

            NSLog("%@", targetString as NSString)

            let fileManager = FileManager.default

            if fileManager.fileExists( atPath: targetString ) == false {
                let content = "" // Just creating empty file.

                //writing
                try content.write(toFile: targetString, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

                //reading
                let readingText = try NSString(contentsOfFile: targetString, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                NSLog("%@", readingText as NSString)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Log shows:

```
2017-04-06 13:35:46.450077-0700 Open New Text File[5177:1035580]     /Users/david/Documents/file.txt
2017-04-06 13:35:46.450257-0700 Open New Text File[5177:1035580]     /Users/david/Documents/file.txt
You don’t have permission to save the file “file.txt” in the folder “Documents”.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer here so I thought I would help out. The issue is the limitations of sandbox. If you add

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write
```

To the entitlements file for the target as an Array with strings for the parent folders you want to watch. In my case I just added "/" to watch everything. Here's mine:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
<array>
    <string>/</string>
</array>
```

This will allow you to access everything relative to the folder mentioned.

One warning: it seems (not thoroughly tested) that if there are other FIFinderSyncController's set up (in other apps), they can effect each other.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. In my case, I just added that as a key and set the type to Boolean with value YES and it allowed me to write (I know specifying individual file system locations is safer, but this works in a pinch). The weird thing is, I don't have Sandbox enabled in Capabilities but I was still denied write permissions to all local folders.This is with Xcode 9.2 beta-4 + macOS 10.13.3 (targeting 10.12.X).

Comment: also, if u need something not a home-relative, but with absolute path, u can use: com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write

Comment: @BenStahl I'm having the same issue, i.e. Sandbox is disabled, but I can not write into a subdirectory of home dir...

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me in a similar case was to select Read/Write in "User Selected Files" in the Capabilities of the Sandbox.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I solved it by setting the "App Sandbox" key to "No" in the "Entitlements File".
Hope this will help.

[image]